# Display Green and Red as another color in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, colors, accessibility

I'm green and red color blind.

Is it possibly in Windows 7 to display green as a shade of another color so I can at least somewhat distinguish green and red when they are next to each?

Comment: There is now an option for this in Windows 10 under color filters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows 7 has a Calibrate color option which you can use to change the individual value settings of the red, green and blue. Basically those colors will be lighter or darker by tweaking this setting.

Do the following:

1. Right click an empty part of your desktop
2. Choose Personalize
3. Click `display` at the bottom left
4. Click `Calibrate Color` at the top left.
5. Follow the wizard, and tweak the colors using the sliders as you see fit.

Normally this is used to correct colors, but in your case it should work to do the opposite.

Comment: I don't believe adjusting the color balance or gamma will effectively allow me to alter the way green is displayed

Comment: I see. I misunderstood your question it seems. I thought you wanted to make red and blue different grey tints so it would be clear that one is a different color than the other.

Comment: There is now an option for this in Windows 10 under color filters if you don't mind updating your answer I would appreciate this.

Comment: Your question was for Windows 7, and this answer reflects that. I can't find it for Windows 10 though. I would therefor suggest you to post a new question asking for this under Windows 10, then answer your own question and provide details as to where. This will keep things tidy on SuperUser. :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to alter the gamma and color settings from your display driver.  All three of the major graphics card vendors (Intel, AIT/AMD, and nVidia) have tools to do this but you'd need their full driver to do it (i.e. nVidia control panel or ATI Catalyst Control Center).

You can use the sliders to alter the intensity of the individual color channels.

Comment: Its not the only way. Its a good way, but not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you could change the shade of green would be to ajust the colour levels on your monitor

Comment: This wouldn't help, because it would just shift *all* colors and therefore others into red and green.

Comment: On some monitors, You can adjust the levels of each individual colour.